# Reading a .txt and Inputting Contents Into a Textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files

I'm trying to read a txt file where a username and password is stored, separated like so:

`Username|Password`

And have python input the two into separate text boxes, essentially a basic "remember me" system for logging in.

`savehover()` changes the foreground color of a widget to a different color if `savepassinput()` is run.

**If the .txt is empty**, it should not run `savepassinput()`, and **pass**.

The code I have here does not give me any errors, but it does not input anything into the text box, nor does it change the color of the button.

Everything in my .txt file is formatted to fit the code, so what seems to be the problem?

```
def savepassinput():
    savehover()
    passtxt = open("rememberme.txt", 'r')
    passtxt.read()
    usr, pas = line.strip().split("|")
    textentry.insert(usr)
    textentry2.insert(pas)

def savepasscheck():
    passtxt = open("rememberme.txt", 'r')
    passtxt.read()
    if passtxt.read() == "":
        pass
    else:
        savepassinput()
    passtxt.close()
```

Comment: Looks like you're not using the file `read()` method properly—it returns the data read, so in the `savepassinput()` function you need to assign it to a variable (such as `line`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `textbox.insert()` in your code is right:

First of all, you should try using [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement, as it assures of properly opening and closing a file.

Second of all, well, you `read()` your file twice. What it does is on the first read it moves the cursor at the end of the file, and then if you read once more, it just reads nothing. So that's why your other function is not being called.

Then, doing the comparison like this: `if passtxt.read() == "":` is not usually the best idea, because your file may contain whitespace like spaces, tabs or newlines. What you can do is `strip()` the string you've just read.

Lastly you can get rid of the useless `if` case with `pass`. Just check if it's not empty -> if it's not, do your saving, if it is, just don't.

Here's how I would write it:

```
def savepasscheck():
    with open("rememberme.txt", 'r') as passtxt:
        if passtxt.read().strip() is not "":
            savepassinput()
```

So this function is reading and checking. You should really follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule, and pass the text you've read to you other function: Like this:

```
def savepasscheck():
    with open("rememberme.txt", 'r') as passtxt:
        content = passtxt.read().strip()
        if content is not "":
            savepassinput(content)

def savepassinput(content):
    savehover()
    usr, pas = content.split("|")
    textentry.insert(usr)
    textentry2.insert(pas)
```